# Problems with Combining and writing filtered data

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, linear-regression, data-cleaning

I have some filtered (with dplyr) data provided below, from a much larger .csv file. I intend on using this as my indep. variable in a linear regression model, also i want to combine these columns and write them to a .csv (as I am sharing this with my team.)

I previously saved these data as "lists" (because of the difference in length of each variable) however when I write to a csv, I have to convert it to a matrix and the data very much not as expected.

The issue here is that each filtered set is one of a different length and therefore different values(CountPD) are attributed to different dates. How can I correctly combine each of these data to a data frame (or something similar), where I can write as a csv and also apply a linear regression in the future(ie where colnames are "Date","y1","y2"...etc)

Y1:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(12083, 12111, 12142, 12172, 
12203, 17500, 17531, 17562, 17590, 17621, 17651), class = "Date"), 
    CountPD = c(1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 0.083, NA, NA, 0.083, 0.083
    )), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 
183L, 184L), class = "data.frame")
```

Y2:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17013, 17044, 17074, 17105, 
17135, NA), class = "Date"), CountPD = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "NA"), class = "data.frame")
```

Y3:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(12783, 12814, 12842, 12873, 
12903, 17500, 17531, 17562, 17590, 17621, 17651), class = "Date"), 
    CountPD = c(NA, 0.333, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.125, 0.125, 0.222, 
    0.2, 0.25)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 156L, 157L, 
158L, 159L, 160L, 161L), class = "data.frame")
```

Y4:

````
structure(list(Date = structure(c(12356, 12417, 12448, 12477, 
12508, 17500, 17531, 17562, 17590, 17621, 17651), class = "Date"), 
    CountPD = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, 0.2, 0.182, 0.182, 0.222, 
    0.25)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 
163L, 164L, 165L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using `tidyverse`. Note that `bind_rows` includes `Y1 = Y1`, etc. so that the assignments on the left of `=` will become the column names after `pivot_wider`, and the names on the right are the data frames provided in this example (also named Y1, Y2, Y3, and Y4). Does this accomplish what you had intended?

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(list(Y1 = Y1, Y2 = Y2, Y3 = Y3, Y4 = Y4), .id = 'Source') %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Date, names_from = Source, values_from = CountPD)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 27 x 5
   Date           Y1    Y2     Y3     Y4
   <date>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2003-01-31  1        NA NA     NA    
 2 2003-02-28  1        NA NA     NA    
 3 2003-03-31  1        NA NA     NA    
 4 2003-04-30 NA        NA NA     NA    
 5 2003-05-31  1        NA NA     NA    
 6 2017-11-30 NA        NA NA      0.2  
 7 2017-12-31  0.083    NA  0.125  0.2  
 8 2018-01-31 NA        NA  0.125  0.182
 9 2018-02-28 NA        NA  0.222  0.182
10 2018-03-31  0.083    NA  0.2    0.222
11 2018-04-30  0.083    NA  0.25   0.25
```

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what i was looking for. Would you mind to explain why bind_rows be more appropriate here than bind_cols?

Comment: `bind_rows` can easily bind multiple datasets together in a list, which you started with. The data frames share common `Date` and `CountPD` columns, so it is logical to combine them with like data elements. One you do that, you will have your data in "long" format, which is often convenient for analyses and further manipulation. But in this case, it sounds like you wanted it converted to "wide" format (thus `pivot_wider`). The `bind_cols` could add columns from one data frame to another, which could work if lengths of dataframes were equal, and the `Date` columns were exactly in common.

Comment: In addition, a "merge" or "join" could be considered in combining data frames together by `Date`.